# Translation of method 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch' failed+

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Translation of method 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch' failed. If this method can be mapped to your custom function, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2132413 for more information.

```
[HttpGet("grid")]
public IActionResult List(SearchVm model)
{
    var searchWord = model.Search.ToRegexSearchText();

    model.SearchItemVm =  _stateOrProvinceRepository.Query()
        .Where(x => Regex.IsMatch(x.Name, searchWord)).Select(g => new SearchItemVm { 
            Name = g.Name,
            Id = g.Id
        }).ToList();

    return Ok(model);
}

public static string ToRegexSearchText(this string input)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
    {
        return input;
    }

    var groupAlpha = new[] {
        "[iİıI]",
        "[gGğĞ]",
        "[üÜuU]",
        "[çÇcC]",
        "[şŞsS]",
        "[öÖoO]"
    };

    input = input.ToLower();
    var words = input.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Distinct();
    words = words.Select(word => $"(.*({string.Concat(word.Select(c => groupAlpha.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Contains(c)) ?? c.ToString()))}))");
    input = string.Concat(words);
    return $"({input})";
}
```

Comment: This is not an ASP.NET issue, this is an issue of the ORM you are using. Which ORM (e.g. Entity Framework) are you using?

Comment: ef core 5.0....

Comment: Then you should use `EF.Functions.Like` instead of the .NET Regex engine. Of course, you could load your complete repository with `.ToList()` and then filter with the .NET Regex engine, but that will kill performance on large tables.